# Importing only a specific part of the docx in Python

Tags: python-3.x, import, docx

I am trying to extract the majority of my docx file when I am importing it to the Python. The best would be if I could tell my code which paragraphs I need or what part of the text I am going to use.

Can anyone help me with that?

I have tried this code:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document('A.docx')
print(len(doc.paragraphs))

print (doc.paragraphs[2].text)
```

but the problem with this is that whenever I hit enter it thinks that a new paragraph has started.

Comment: What do you mean by "telling your code which paragraphs you need"
Also, what do you mean by "it thinks that a new paragraph starts with enter"?

When you hit enter in word, or any docx formatter, you create new paragraph.

Comment: Sorry for the poor vocab and confusing language, but I am looking for an answer hot to get chapters out of a docx. I tried to say that approaching this problem with paragraphs did not work for me.